# Observable transformers made of Subjects

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I am currently implementing a pattern that has a view-viewmodel circular dependency. Though its really not dependency because they don't know about each other, all they know is that there is a stream of events and a stream of states. I came up with an idea of making the viewModel implement a function called `toTransformer()` which returns an `ObservableTransformer` that's composed of two subjects, an event subject and a state subject.

```
private val eventStream: PublishSubject<MainEvent> = PublishSubject.create()

private val stateSink: BehaviorSubject<MainState> = BehaviorSubject.create()

...

fun asTransformer(): ObservableTransformer<MainEvent, MainState> =
        ObservableTransformer {
            it.subscribe { eventStream.onNext(it) }
            stateSink
        }
```

And is used like this

```
view.events().compose(viewModel.asTransformer()).subscribe { view.render(it) }
```

**Questions**

- Is it okay to do this?
- What could go wrong with this implementation.
- Will the inner subscription be disposed if the subscription is disposed?
- Can this be improved to a better form?

**Edit**

This is how event and state relates.

```
eventStream.map { it.toAction() }
    .compose(actionToResult())
    .scan (MainState.initial(), reducer())
    .subscribe {
        stateSink.onNext(it)
    }
```

Comment: How state is derived from event? it's not clear how do you handle it?

Comment: hi @yosriz please see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you based it off of this, but Jake Wharton has a [great presentation on this kind of architecture](http://jakewharton.com/the-state-of-managing-state-with-rxjava/).

> Is it okay to do this?

In general, sure.

> What could go wrong with this implementation.

One thing you probably want to be careful of is that you essentially have one big event loop. If your event loop dies, the UI will be non-responsive. Correct error handling is even more important than before. I'm sure your code snippets above are a simplified version of what you really have, but consider that without an error handling block, failures in your inner subscription will bubble up to your outer subscription which will itself fail. At this point, there will be no active subscriptions to UI events.

> Will the inner subscription be disposed if the subscription is disposed?

No. It's not in the same chain.

> Can this be improved to a better form?

Especially in consideration of the previous answer, you may want to get rid of the inner subscription so that it's all one chain. An easy way is to use `flatMap` instead of subscribing.

Comment: Yes its base on jake's presentation.
The error handling is inside `actionToResult()`. I was being careful to put `onErrorReturn()` on every action sub `transformer` (that compose my main `transformer`, `actionToResult()`) to emit `ErrorResult` instead of propagating `Exceptions`.

Thank you, you're right, `'flatMap()` how could I forget. Thank you so much.

Comment: `fun asTransformer(): ObservableTransformer<MainEvent, MainState> =
            ObservableTransformer {
                it.flatMap {
                    eventStream.onNext(it)
                    stateSink
                }
            }`

Comment: I got problem now. I dont have a supporting documentation but, when a `BehaviorSubject`is placed inside a `flatMap()`. It won't emit the last data emitted.

Comment: Ops, correction. Behavior subject is working well, but in every emission, new subscription to it will be added

Comment: You don't want to `flatMap` to `onNext`. `flatMap` to the actual stream. I haven't thought through your specific implementation too hard, but I suspect `PublishSubject` and `BehaviorSubject` are not necessarily the classes you need here.